# Angular js ui grid issue of having white space after the column name row

Tags: html, angularjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghFVc.jpg)

A large white space after the column name row in the uigrid and then after all the datas are displayed,how can i solve this issue,anybody please help me.

Angular //////////////

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {

$scope.gridOptions = {

```
showColumnFooter: true,
exporterMenuCsv: true,
enableGridMenu: true,
enableFiltering: true,
showGridFooter: false,


onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  $scope.gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor($scope.singleFilter, 200);
},
paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
paginationPageSize: 10,
showColumnFooter: true,

columnDefs: [
  {
    field: 'Name',





  },
  {
    field: 'IE',
    visible: false,
    enableCellEdit: false,
    enableFiltering: false
  },

  {

    field: 'Amount',
    enableFiltering: false,



  }

]
```

};

var gridOptions = [];
  $scope.gridOptions.data = 'gridData';
Here is my html and angular code i was currently working .

Comment: can you provide more details? show your HTML and AngularJS code to be able to help you.

Comment: hlo i added my code you can check it now